# Problem with Flex Builder

Tags: flex3

I have created on sample mxml application. While running the
application, getting error:

File Not found: in bin-debug folder the mxml is not compiled to html.

Suppose i have created file name: newFlexTraining.mxml.when i run this
mxml, getting error, newFlexTraining.html is not available in bin-
debug.I checked in bin-debug folder in flerx builder, the html file is
not created. Earlier it was working fine.But now i am getting this
problem. Can you any one pls explain me ASAP.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you modify html-template?

Delete everything from bin-debug folder, clean the project and rebuild it.

`in bin-debug folder the mxml is not compiled to html` is this the original message? Post the original error message.

Comment: Original Error Message:

File Not Found:

file://../Flex Builder 3/FlexTraining/bin-debug/sampleFlexApplication.html

Comment: see if this page helps http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=183083